# Does $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\operatorname{exp}(H_n)}{n+1} $ exist?

Tags: limits, euler-mascheroni-constant

> **Question:**
>   Does $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\operatorname{exp}(H_n)}{n+1} $ exist?  If so, what is its value?

I know that the answer to the second part is $e^\gamma$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant, but I don't know how to get there.

The solution probably involves the definition of $\gamma$:
$$\gamma = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left( \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} -\ln n\right)$$

Comment: Well I have got one hundred of problems about limit (i'm a student) and in the correction I just have the result and I had problems with this limit for weeks so I ask my question here. (And sorry if I make some english mistake)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\exp(H_n)}{n+1} &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\exp(H_n)}{\exp\ln(n+1)} \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\exp(H_n - \ln(n+1)\right)\\
&=\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(H_n - \ln(n+1)\right)\right)\tag{$\star$}\\
&=\exp(\gamma)
\end{align}
The move to line $(\star)$ is justified because $\exp(\cdot)$ is a continuous function.